# Using a BoxSelect class inside a runnable method in a thread (java)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This is how I am trying to execute my code.

```
private final class BoxSelect implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        setView(view);
        setMotionEvent(motionEvent);
        if (t1.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
        {
            t1.start();
            if (getHit() == false) {
                t2.start();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have two thread created called t1 and t2 which take the two runnable methods r1 and r1 as parameters:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
```

R1 is defined as:

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ENTERING RUN t1");
        class BoxSelect implements View.OnTouchListener {

            Drawable hitTarget = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hit);
            Drawable missTarget = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.miss);

            View view1 = getView();
            MotionEvent motionEvent1 = getMotionEvent();

            public void whenCreate()
            {
                System.out.println("HERE t1");
                hit = false;
                boolean goToElse = true;
                boolean hit2 = false;
                boolean goToElse2 = true;
                if (motionEvent1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
                            String coord = b.getBoard()[i][j];
                            if (view == ids[i][j]) {
                                System.out.println("ATTACKING " + b.getCompTempBoard()[i][j]);
                                player.basicAttack(b.getBoard(), coord, ai);
                            }
                            if (view == ids[i][j] && b.getCompTempBoard()[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("HIT")) {
                                System.out.println("Hit GUI");
                                if (ids[i][j].getBackground().equals(hitTarget)) {
                                    hit = true;
                                    goToElse = false;
                                } else {
                                    ids[i][j].setBackgroundDrawable(hitTarget);
                                    System.out.println("ert 1 " + b.getCompTempBoard()[i][j]);
                                    playerCount++;
                                    if (playerCount == 10) {
                                        player.endGame();
                                        b.incrementPlayerCount();
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                        builder1.setMessage("YOU WIN :)\nScore is:\nPlayer: " + b.getPlayerWinCount() + "\nComputer: " + b.getCompWinCount());
                                        builder1.setCancelable(true);
                                        builder1.setNegativeButton("OK",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(AttackShips6.this, MainMenu.class);
                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                    }
                                                });

                                        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                        alert11.show();
                                        for (int k = 0; k < ids2.length; k++) {
                                            for (int r = 0; r < ids2.length; r++) {
                                                if (b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("HIT") || b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("NULL NOT HIT")) {
                                                    ids[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(hitTarget);
                                                }
                                                if (b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("MISS") || b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase(b.getBoard()[k][r])) {
                                                    ids[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                                                }
                                                if (b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("HIT") || b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("NULL NOT HIT")) {
                                                    ids2[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(hitTarget);
                                                }
                                                if (b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("MISS") || b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase(b.getBoard()[k][r])) {
                                                    ids2[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    hit = true;
                                    goToElse = false;
                                }
                            } else if (view == ids[i][j] && b.getCompTempBoard()[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("MISS")) {
                                System.out.println("MISS GUI 1");
                                if (ids[i][j].getBackground().equals(missTarget)) {
                                    hit = true;
                                    goToElse = false;
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("MISS GUI");
                                    ids[i][j].setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                                    System.out.println("ert 2 " + b.getCompTempBoard()[i][j]);
                                    hit = true;
                                    goToElse = true;
                                }

                            }
                            if (goToElse == true) {
                                hit = false;
                                System.out.println("MISS PLAYER GUI");
                                view.setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and R2 is:

```
Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("ENTERING RUN t2");
            try {
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1);
                System.out.println("HERE 2");
                class BoxSelect implements View.OnTouchListener {
                    Drawable hitTarget = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hit);
                    Drawable missTarget = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.miss);
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    System.out.println("HERE t2");

                    if (hit == false) {

                        System.out.println("SLEEPING 2");
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        System.out.println("COMPUTERS TURN");
                        ai.advancedAttack(b.getBoard(), ai.getRandomCoordinate_For_Attacking_6x6(), player);
                        System.out.println("First attack: " + ai.getFirstCoord());
                        boolean goAgain = true;
                        while (goAgain == true) {
                            for (int w = 0; w < ids2.length; w++) {
                                for (int y = 0; y < ids2.length; y++) {
                                    if (b.getBoard()[w][y].equalsIgnoreCase(ai.getFirstCoord()) && b.getTempBoard()[w][y].equalsIgnoreCase("HIT")) {
                                        System.out.println("DR 1");
                                        ids2[w][y].setBackgroundDrawable(hitTarget);
                                        ai.setFirstCoord(ai.getNextCoordToAttack());
                                        System.out.println("Next: " + ai.getFirstCoord());
                                        ai.advancedAttack(b.getBoard(), ai.getFirstCoord(), player);
                                        System.out.println("After attack in loop");
                                        goAgain = true;
                                        CompCount++;
                                        if (CompCount == 10) {
                                            b.incrementCompCount();
                                            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                            builder1.setMessage("YOU LOSE :(\n" + "Score is:\n" + "Player: \n" + b.getPlayerWinCount() + "\nComputer: " + b.getCompWinCount());
                                            builder1.setCancelable(true);
                                            builder1.setNegativeButton("OK",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                            dialog.cancel();
                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(AttackShips6.this, MainMenu.class);
                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                            alert11.show();
                                            for (int k = 0; k < ids2.length; k++) {
                                                for (int r = 0; r < ids2.length; r++) {
                                                    if (b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("HIT") || b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("NULL NOT HIT")) {
                                                        ids[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(hitTarget);
                                                    }
                                                    if (b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("MISS") || b.getCompTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase(b.getBoard()[k][r])) {
                                                        ids[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                                                    }
                                                    if (b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("HIT") || b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("NULL NOT HIT")) {
                                                        ids2[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(hitTarget);
                                                    }
                                                    if (b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase("MISS") || b.getTempBoard()[k][r].equalsIgnoreCase(b.getBoard()[k][r])) {
                                                        ids2[k][r].setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } else if (b.getBoard()[w][y].equalsIgnoreCase(ai.getFirstCoord()) && b.getTempBoard()[w][y].equalsIgnoreCase("MISS")) {
                                        System.out.println("DR 2");
                                        ids2[w][y].setBackgroundDrawable(missTarget);
                                        ai.setFirstCoord(ai.getNextCoordToAttack());
                                        goAgain = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return hit;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println("IN CATCH");
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }
};`
```

I originally had these two together as one block, but separated it as I wish to pause thread 2 from occurring for one second after thread 2.

The problem I am having is that the BoxSelect class is not getting executed inside the R1 and R2 and so none of the code is executing. Any help on this matter would be appreciated!